# Read value from table and apply condition in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe: df1

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| A    | 100    | null   |    200 |
| B    | 10000  | 300    |     10 |
| c    | null   | 10     |    100 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

second dataframe: df2:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| X    | 1000 |
| Y    | 2002 |
| Z    | 3000 |
+------+------+
```

I want to read the values from table1 like value1,value2 and value3

Apply condition to table2 with new columns:

cond1: **when name= A and col2>value1, flag it to Y or N**

cond2: **when name= B and col2>value2 then Y or N**

cond3: **when name =c  and col2>value1 and col2> value3, then Y or N**

source code:

```
df2.withColumn("cond1",when($"col2")>value1,lit("Y)).otherwise(lit("N"))
df2.withColumn("cond2",when($"col2")>value2,lit("Y)).otherwise(lit("N"))
df2.withColumn("cond3",when($"col2")>value1 && when($"col2")>value3,lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N"))
```

output:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Col1 | col2 | cond1 | cond2 | cond3 |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| X    | 1000 | Y     | Y     | y     |
| Y    | 2002 | N     | Y     | Y     |
| Z    | 3000 | Y     | Y     | Y     |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: How are the rows matched between your two dataframes?

Comment: I want to read the values from value1 , value2, value3 store in variable, and apply condition based on value

Comment: @vikv I think what he is asking is, should the "Name" column in df1 equal to "Col1" in df2 for the rows to be matched. Or is it based on order or something else?

Comment: yes shaido, this what i was looking

Comment: I still don't understand what value1, value2  and value3 are in your example. Do you add the three values or do you want to do the process for each row in the first df?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can join the two dataframes and create the condition columns as shown below.  A couple of notes:

1) With the described conditions,`null` in df1 is replaced with `Int.MinValue` for simplified integer comparison

2) Since df1 is small, `broadcast` join is used to minimize sorting/shuffling for better performance

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("A", 100, Int.MinValue, 200),
  ("B", 10000, 300, 10),
  ("C", Int.MinValue, 10, 100)
).toDF("Name", "value1", "value2", "value3")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("A", 1000),
  ("B", 2002),
  ("C", 3000),
  ("A", 5000),
  ("A", 150),
  ("B", 250),
  ("B", 12000),
  ("C", 50)
).toDF("Col1", "col2")

val df3 = df2.join(broadcast(df1), df2("Col1") === df1("Name")).select(
  df2("Col1"),
  df2("col2"),
  when(df2("col2") > df1("value1"), "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond1"),
  when(df2("col2") > df1("value2"), "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond2"),
  when(df2("col2") > df1("value1") && df2("col2") > df1("value3"), "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond3")
)

df3.show
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Col1| col2|cond1|cond2|cond3|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   A| 1000|    Y|    Y|    Y|
|   B| 2002|    N|    Y|    N|
|   C| 3000|    Y|    Y|    Y|
|   A| 5000|    Y|    Y|    Y|
|   A|  150|    Y|    Y|    N|
|   B|  250|    N|    N|    N|
|   B|12000|    Y|    Y|    Y|
|   C|   50|    Y|    Y|    N|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `rowNo` column in both `dataframes` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val tempdf1 = df1.withColumn("rowNo", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("Name")))
val tempdf2 = df2.withColumn("rowNo", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("Col1")))
```

Then you can `join` them with the created column as below

```
val joinedDF = tempdf2.join(tempdf1, Seq("rowNo"), "left")
```

Finally you can use `select` and `when` function to get the final dataframe

```
joinedDF.select($"Col1",
  $"col2",
  when($"col2">$"value1" || $"value1".isNull, "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond1"),
  when($"col2">$"value2" || $"value2".isNull, "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond2"),
  when(($"col2">$"value1" && $"col2">$"value3") || $"value3".isNull, "Y").otherwise("N").as("cond3"))
```

you should have your desired dataframe as

```
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|Col1|col2|cond1|cond2|cond3|
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|X   |1000|Y    |Y    |Y    |
|Y   |2002|N    |Y    |Y    |
|Z   |3000|Y    |Y    |Y    |
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: thanks for response.but this scenario doesnt work if df1 and df2 have different number of rows. In my scenario df1 is of 3 rows small table, but my df2 is always big. Just I gave example usecase in question.

Comment: if thats the case then how do you compare for df1 having more than three rows and df2 having only three rows? can you explain that? which rows of df1 will be compared with which rows of df2?